# Sql Max() issue

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have a table where I want to display `cakename` and `cakeid` with max `price`/`slice`. What is the easiest way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Both column are price/slice integer type ??

Comment: do you want to select maximum *price* or maximum *slices* or maximum *price per slice* ?

Comment: Try this **order by (price/slice) desc** @Sahil Malhotra

Comment: A worthy task, certainly, but it does sound like homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to print just one entry having max price/slice use limit clause after order by descending as below

```
  select 
     cakeid,
     cakename,
     -- slices,
     -- status,
     -- price,
     price/slices as price_per_slice
  from table1 
  order by (price/slices) desc limit 1;
```

If you want all the entries to display having max price/slice then use subquery as below

```
  select 
     cakeid,
     cakename,
     -- slices,
     -- status,
     -- price,
     price/slices as price_per_slice
  from table1 where (price/slices) = ( select max(price/slices) from table1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this.

```
SELECT  cakename,
        cakeid,
        (price/slice) as col1
FROM CakeTable order by col1 desc
```

By doing this you will get cakeid, cakename and price/slice in descending order

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   cakename,
         cakeid,
         price,
         slice
FROM     CakeTable
ORDER BY price/slice DESC
```

Think this would work so you only display what matters. You can change the 
order in the other way by replacing `DESC` with `ASC`.

Hope this works.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  cakename,
        cakeid,
        MAX(price) AS [MaxPrice]
FROM CakeTable
GROUP BY cakename,cakeid
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use group by clause:

```
SELECT CakeName,
    CakeID,
    MAX(Price)
FROM CakeTable
Group by Price,CakeID,CakeName
```

Comment: Why Price in the GROUP BY, combined with MAX(Price)?